# Determinant of matrix with binomial coefficient elements equal to $\binom{2n-1}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, determinant

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A_n$ with elements $a_{ij}=\binom{n+i-1}{j}$, $1 \le i \le n$, $1 \le j \le n$, I noticed that its determinant $\lvert A_n \rvert$ seem to satisfy:

$$\lvert A_n \rvert = \binom{2n-1}{n}$$

The sequence is at [OEIS A001700](https://oeis.org/A001700) (shifted by $1$).

How could the identity be proved?

Comment: Your determinant is a special case of the binomial determinant investigated by Gessel in [Binomial Determinants, Paths, and Hook Length Formulae.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885901215) You can either use Lemma 8 repeatedly to prove your determinant evaluates to $\binom{2n-1}{n}$, or you can get a combinatorial proof by using the combinatorial interpretation given by Theorem 1. I may write an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your determinant fits into a larger of determinants which have a very cool combinatorial interpretation, which was investigate in [Binomial Determinants, Paths, and Hook Length Formulae](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885901215) by Ira Gessel, to which I owe all the insight in this answer.

Let
$$
A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\},\quad B=\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}
$$
be arbitrary equal-size subsets of the nonnegative integers, sorted so that $0\le a_1<a_2<\dots<a_n$ and $0\le b_1<b_2<\dots<b_n$. Using Gessel's terminology, we define the *binomial determinant* for $A$ and $B$ to be the determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $\binom{a_i}{b_j}$. That is,
$$
\binom{a_1,\dots,a_n}{b_1,\dots,b_n}\stackrel{\text{def}}=\det\left[\binom{a_i}{b_j}\right]_{1\le i,j\le n}
$$
This reduces to your question upon setting $A=\{n,\dots,2n-1\}$ and $B=\{1,\dots,n\}$.

The following two Lemmas are useful for simplifying binomial determinants.

> **Lemma 1**  If $b_1\neq 0$, then $$\binom{a_1,\dots,a_n}{b_1,\dots,b_n}=\frac{a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n}{b_1\cdot b_2\cdots b_n}\binom{a_1-1,\dots,a_n-1}{b_1-1,\dots,b_n-1}$$

*Proof:* Apply the absorption lemma $\binom{a_i}{b_j}=\frac{a_i}{b_j}\binom{a_i-1}{b_j-1}$ to each entry of the matrix defining $\binom{a_1,\dots,a_n}{b_1,\dots,b_n}$, then for each $i,j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, pull out an $a_i$ from the $i^{th}$ row of the matrix and a $\frac1{b_j}$ from the $j^{th}$ column. $\;\;\;\blacksquare$

> **Lemma 2:** $$\binom{a,a+1,\dots,a+n-1}{0,b_2,\dots,b_n}=\binom{a,a+1,\dots,a+n-2}{b_2-1,\dots,b_n-1}$$

*Proof idea:* This can be proven with elementary row operations. Let $M$ be the $n\times n$ matrix defining the binomial determinant on the LHS, so $M_{i,j}=\binom{a+i-1}{b_j}$, with the convention $b_1=0$. Start by subtracting the first row of $M$ from all subsequent rows. Then, subtract the second row of the result from all subsequent rows. Continue in this fashion, subtracting each row of $M$ from all subsequent rows in order from top to bottom, doing $\binom{n}2$ subtractions in all. In the final result, the first column will have a $1$ in its first entry and zeroes everywhere else. If you cofactor expand along this column, the result is exactly a smaller matrix defining the binomial determinant on the RHS. $\;\;\;\blacksquare$

Now, onto your specific case. You want to compute
$$
\binom{n,n+1,\dots,2n-1}{1,2,\dots,n}
$$
Apply the first Lemma, this equals
$$
\frac{n(n+1)\cdots(2n-1)}{1\cdot2\cdots n}\binom{n-1,n,\dots,2n-2}{0,1,\dots,n-1}
$$
Note that the fraction out front is equal to $\binom{2n-1}n$, so we just need to show the remaining binomial determinant is equal to $1$. This is accomplished by repeatedly applying the second Lemma.

---

There is also a combinatorial interpretation the binomial determinant in terms of collections of disjoint lattice paths. In this context, a lattice path is a path on $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ where each step is either one unit up or one unit right. Now, with sets $A$ and $B$ defined as before, define two sets of source vertices and target vertices as follows:
$$
\text{source vertices}: \quad (0,-a_1),(0,-a_2),\dots,(0,-a_n)\\
\text{target vertices}: \quad (b_1,-b_1),(b_2,-b_2),\dots,(b_n,-b_n)\\
$$
Then $\binom{a_1,\dots,a_n}{b_1,\dots,b_n}$ enumerates the number of ways to choose $n$ vertex-disjoint lattice paths, where each path connects a distinct source vertex to a distinct target vertex. The fact that this works is a direct consequence of the Lindström–Gessel–Viennot lemma.

If you apply this combinatorial interpretation to your problem, you can get a combinatorial proof that your determinant is $\binom{2n-1}n$. Specifically, when $A=\{n,\dots,2n-1\}$ and $B=\{1,\dots,n\}$, you can show the heights of the rightmost horizontal edges of the $n$ paths must form a strictly increasing sequence in order for the paths to not hit each other. Therefore, choosing the paths is equivalent to choosing a strictly increasing function $\{1,\dots,n\}\to \{1,\dots,2n-1\}$. The number of such functions is $\binom{2n-1}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think that this can be easily extended to prove that if we replace the binomial coefficients above with Stirling numbers of the first and second kind, with the same indexes, we get a determinant of $n!^{n+1}$ and $n!^{n-1}$ respectively?

Comment: And with Lah numbers the determinant is $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{(n+k)!}{(k+1)!}}$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, those are unrelated results. Maybe someone else on MSE knows more?

Comment: I have posted a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/423216/136218) on MO for the determinant of matrices with Stirling numbers. Somebody found a generalization to Comtet numbers.

Comment: That is a fascinating generalization! Thanks for sharing.